# accessing controls of similar type in a loop in vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am trying to access a group of similarly named rectangle shapes in a loop and change their backcolor property in vb.net 2010 language

Answer (score -1):

As you have not specified if its is web site or desktop, I am assuming, it is more related to web.

You can use jquery for changing the color:

More information can be found at:

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Or more related to your requirement can be found at:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/534-The-Beauty-Of-The-jQuery-Each-Method.htm

Comment: it is ambigious but I think the OP is asking for a VB.NET Windows Application since Shapes have the a property named BackColor in .NET